# Javascript function undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am fairly new to `javascript` and `jquery`. I thought i had learned enough to do this, but apparently not. I think the code is fairly self explanatory.

The problem is that `ArrowDir` is apparently undefined. It looks defined to me, but I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

```
function ArrowDir(){
    var up = function(){
        $("#arrow").attr('src','up_arrow.jpg');
    };

    var down = function(){
        $("#arrow").attr('src','down_arrow.jpg');
    };
}

$(function () {
    if($("#toggle").onclick){
        ArrowDir().down();
    };
});
```

I've tried assigning the function as a variable, `var ArrowDir = function()`, but it doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: I've updated the indentation and formatting to match the original post, and left the missing quote on purpose. Please update the code in your question if the missing quote was a transcription error.

Comment: Also, please review [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you haven't already.

Comment: Don't have a clue how that happened. I think i accidentally broke it up when pasting. It is fine in my code. It isn't the problem, either way. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418669/javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the `up` and `down` values in the manner that you've written. You'd need to simply call `down()` from within the `ArrowDir` body, unless you've added those functions to the `ArrowDir` return value:

```
ArrowDir() {
  var up = ...;
  var down = ...;
  return {
    up: up,
    down: down
  };
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're not using `ArrowDir` for anything other than encapsulating the `up` and `down` functions, you should just declare `ArrowDir` as an object, and call `ArrowDir.up()` and `ArrowDir.down()`:

```
var ArrowDir = {
    up: function () {
        ...
    },
    down: function () {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the missing quote after `"#toggle` is a typo, I'm not sure how you expect your code to work.

Here's how it runs, in prose:

> - Define a function `ArrowDir`.
> - When ready, attach a click handler
> - When clicked, call `ArrowDir`
>
>   - In `ArrowDir`, define two local variables `up` and `down`, each with a function to do something.
>   - There is no `return` statement, so return nothing
> - Call the `down` method of the "nothing" object. ERROR

See?

Try adding `return {up:up,down:down};` to the end of your `ArrowDir` function.

Answer (score 0):

The var up and down you have defined inside ArrowDir are not accessible outside the scope of that function.

The simplest way you could fix this, if this is a one-time kind of function, is just to put the up/down behavior in your jQuery function, like this:

```
$(function () {
    if($("#toggle").onclick){
        $("#arrow").attr('src','up_arrow.jpg');
    } else {
        $("#arrow").attr('src','down_arrow.jpg');
    }
});
```

If you just want to namespace these functions for reusability you could make an object literal instead:

```
ArrowDir = {
  up: function(){
    $("#arrow").attr('src','up_arrow.jpg');
  },
  down: function(){
    $("#arrow").attr('src','down_arrow.jpg');
  }
};
```

Then you can call: `ArrowDir.up()` or `ArrowDir.down()` elsewhere.

For what it's worth, if your goal is just to namespace these functions for reusability, I would say the object literal syntax makes more sense to me.

Or, if you really want to do it as a function call, as Kolink has pointed out, the up/down functions need to be in the return value. You could write that like this...

```
function ArrowDir() {
  var up = function(){
    $("#arrow").attr('src','up_arrow.jpg');
  }
  var down = function(){
    $("#arrow").attr('src','down_arrow.jpg');
  }
  return {up:up,down:down};
}
```

Or like this...

```
function ArrowDir() {
  return {
    up: function(){
      $("#arrow").attr('src','up_arrow.jpg');
    },
    down: function(){
      $("#arrow").attr('src','down_arrow.jpg');
    }
  };
}
```

Now calling `ArrowDir().down()` should work.

Comment: Kinda, since you're completely changing the structure of their code. What if `ArrowDir` is used elsewhere?

Comment: Ok @Kolink, much more discussion added with multiple different approaches including just fixing his return value...

Answer (score 0):

`ArrowDir().down()` here's your problem. Just because you define a variable in the ArrowDir function doesn't make it a method/property of it. You have to use Prototype Inheritance.

EDIT:

```
//Something like this:
ArrowDir.prototype.down = function() {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Now you can call `ArrowDir.down()`.
Doing this extends the properties (things it can do) of the object `ArrowDir`. You're adding a method to it.

Comment: "You have to use Prototype Inheritance" - Care to explain how?

Comment: I think this video can explain much better then I ever could:
https://tutsplus.com/lesson/prototypal-inheritance-and-refactoring-the-slider/

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) MSO answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the object this way. In your function you are creating them insdied the scope of itself. SO it is not accessible outside.

```
function ArrowDir() {


}
ArrowDir.prototype.up = function () {
    $("#arrow").attr('src', 'up_arrow.jpg');
};

ArrowDir.prototype.down = function () {
    $("#arrow").attr('src', 'down_arrow.jpg');
}
```

and access it as

```
$(function () {
    if($("#toggle").onclick){
      var arrow =  new ArrowDir(); // call the constructor to create a new instance
      arrow.down(); // invoke the method
    };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. This would only work if the function call were `new ArrowDir().down()`.

Comment: It adds excessive complexity?

Comment: @Kolink Why. it just simple protoyping right. I did not say it has to be this way either.

Comment: @Kolink sure but no i dont agree regd `more work`, i am just adding to to the prototype. its just another way. Dont this this is worth a  downvote.